# SDL Web 8 - DXA 1.5 - Blueprint Hierarchy

Tags: dxa, web8

I am new to DXA 1.5 on Web 8. Need some details on Blueprint hierarchy being offered as part DXA 1.5 initial setup. My understanding is as follows:

- `000 Empty` - Base publication.
- `100 Master` - Schema, Category/Keywords, Core Templates, Core Design and Settings.
- `110 DXA Site Type` - Page Types, Global pages like homepage, error pages, _cloneable content. All pages which are common across multiple websites.
- `200 Example Content` - User content
- `400 Example Site` - Website.

Can anyone please validate my understanding of these publications.

Further Questions:

1. `200 Example Content` is getting inherited from `110 DXA Site types`, why? 
   As per my understanding inheritance is only to make _cloneable content available for master content (`200 Example Content`). Can anyone please validate?

Answer (score 2):

Your initial understanding is quite okay I would say:

- `000 Empty` - Base Publication, Empty Parent, we use this Publication to make sure all future created Publicationd, can have at least a single common parent, so everything belongs to a single BluePrint. Because we keep this Publication "empty" (i.e. no items other than the defaults), it will never harm to use it as a parten for any new Publication.
- `100 Master` - Schema, Category/Keywords, Template Building Blocks, HTML Design and Settings for modules. Like the Schema Publication you see in most BluePrints, but it also contains Templates, since with DXA there is no need to separate design out in a different Publication (as all our Templates are the same anyways, it is only the views and HTML designs that would differ).
- `110 DXA Site Type` - XPM Page Types (incl. prototype Components), XPM Content Types, Include Pages (Header, Footer, etc.), Home Page, Error Page, Structure Groups (`system\assets` subtree) and our default Business Process Type. This Publication is marked as a `Site Type`, for use in the Site Wizard in Web 8, so you can create "empty" DXA Publications based on it.
- `200 Example Content` - Example content, what the name says basically
- `400 Example Site` - Example website, what the name says basically

For your further questions, why is `200 Example Content` inheriting from `110 DXA Site types`?

Well because `110 DXA Site types` contains all of the items required for a default DXA Publication. For the Content, thatbasically is the Schemas and Folders (Schemas inherited through `100 Master` of course). But it also shows the BluePrint you would create when you want to make a new microsite in DXA. You would create a **Content** Publication and a **Site** Publication. Both would inherit from `110 DXA Site types`, and the **Site** Publication, would also inherit from the **Content** Publication. That way you can create translated **Content** Publications, and thus translated Sites.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Bart for a quick response. 
Will it be a good idea to remove "110 DXA Site Type" publication.

- I will create content types/ clone-able content in **020 Global content** instead.
- Rest of the items ( XPM Page Types, Include Pages (Header, Footer, etc.), Home Page, Error Page, Structure Groups (system\assets subtree) and our default Business Process Type ) I will move to **400 Website Master**. This will be home to all the pages which are global and will be present across all countries. I would like to use this site for global xpm edits i.e. page creation etc without translation. 
  **400 Website Master** will then be used as **Site Type** for my micro sites.
- Microsite will then inherit from **400 Website Master** and **030 Content Language** Publications

Comment: To me it sounds like your second bullet is a complex way of saying that you want to rename "110 DXA Site Type" to "400 Website Master"... :-) Of course, you're free to do so.

Comment: I have the same question - why can't we move everything in 110 DXA Site Type to the 400 publication (and just remove 110)? It's not the same as renaming 110 DXA Site Type to 400 Website Master, because 400 would still be inheriting from 200, not the other way around...