# What is a good BluePrint Structure for two applications with DXA?

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, sites-9, blueprint

We are using SDL Sites 9.0 with DXA 2.2.
I am a beginner on DXA and want to start development for two .NET applications using also webcomponents.
Each application has it own content, but can share some schema's if possible.
Deployment is for one location and one language.

We imported the Core Example publications.
000 Empty
100 Master
110 DXA Site Type
200 Example Content
400 Example Site

Comment: See Bart's explanation of the DXA Example BluePrint here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15288/sdl-web-8-dxa-1-5-blueprint-hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackexchange. I do recommend looking into DXA online documentation for [SDL Sites Blueprint](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v12&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-B6BF077A-E938-42AB-8C74-B3D5B3EB4FE6&addHistory=true&query=blueprint&scope=&tid=30f5fc3a-fa4b-4a4a-a948-a51d9ea7ea4e&filename=GUID-B6BF077A-E938-42AB-8C74-B3D5B3EB4FE6.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B6BF077A-E938-42AB-8C74-B3D5B3EB4FE6&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20DXA-v12%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dblueprint&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1593616058874&currentQuery=blueprint&currentScope=).

Based on the description posted above you may end up with

```
000 Empty - Keep is empty
100 Master - Keep your schemas
110 DXA Site Type - Your design elements
200 Website Content 1 - Rename 200 Example Content to your content master 1 
200 Website Content 1 - Create new content master 2
400 Site 1- Rename 400 Example Site to your website 1 and inherit from Content 1 and Design
400 Site 2- Create new website 2 and inherit from Content 2 and Design
```

You can alternatively create a Global content master, if there are global elements shared across your blueprint. You could also [promote and demote](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-375400B9-6AAC-4C31-840A-9321E7F870DB&addHistory=true&query=promote&scope=&tid=a57a42e6-8796-45b4-8a0c-154c72a311ba&filename=GUID-375400B9-6AAC-4C31-840A-9321E7F870DB.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-375400B9-6AAC-4C31-840A-9321E7F870DB&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dpromote&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1593624012397&currentQuery=promote&currentScope=) items to achieve optimum hierarchy.

Please note that blueprinting is the backbone for an SDL implementation. There is no right way to implementing a blueprint but it is imperative that the BP can scale for future scenarios. Getting some [SDL training](https://www.sdl.com/trainings/) may also be a good idea!